# USVN Database issue

Tags: svn

I have tried to install USVN and I have this issue.

The Database is created, but does not generate anything. Not a single table.

[DB installation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wR62c.png)

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

I have found a solution, I have changed the file of the installation mysql.sql from the usvn file for this change [code_change_mysql.sql](https://github.com/usvn/usvn/blob/master/src/app/install/sql/mysql.sql)